# Angular 6 agm using google autocomplete

Tags: angular, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api, google-places

I'm running an Angular application. I have on my front-end a map being rendered through angular google maps (agm-map). I'm having an issue when using google maps places autocomplete api. So when I start typing the address it starts populating below as I type and if I click one of the populated address it appears on the map which is good. My issue is if i paste an address why doesn't my pasted address appear on the map? To get this working I have to paste the address and then when the address populated below I Have to click it. Even though is the EXACT address that i pasted to the one being populated. Below I will post my mapsapiloader. Is there a way to make it simulate like when I paste the address onto the search bar it automatically selects the first option in the drop down list of the autocomplete addresses?

```
this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
  const autocompleteInput = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.pickupInputElementRef.nativeElement, {
    types: ['address']
  });

  const autocompleteOutput = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.pickupOutputElementRef.nativeElement, {
    types: ['address']
  });
  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(autocompleteInput, 'pickup');
  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(autocompleteOutput, 'destination');
});



private setupPlaceChangedListener(autocomplete: any, inputType: string) {
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        const place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (place.geometry === undefined) {
          return;
        }
        if (inputType === 'pickup') {
          this.service.origin = { longitude: place.geometry.location.lng(), latitude: place.geometry.location.lat() };
          this.service.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
        } else {
          this.service.destination = { longitude: place.geometry.location.lng(), latitude: place.geometry.location.lat() };
          this.service.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
        }
        if (this.service.directionsDisplay === undefined) {
          this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
            this.service.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
          });
        }
        this.service.updateDirections();
        this.zoom = 12;
      });
    });
  }
```